# Gitlab CI .NET6 docker build issue

Tags: docker, .net-core, gitlab, .net-6.0, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a GitLab CI/CD project to build a NET6 application into a docker image, which is pushed to AWS ECR. My issue is manifested in the continuous failure of 'COPY . .' or any other command after 'restore' of my targeted project.

Repo structure:

```
repo root
-   projectFolder
        - projectAPI
            -   projectAPI.csproj
            -   DockerFile
        - nuget.config
        - referencedClassLibrary1
        - referencedClassLibrary2
        - .sln
-   gitlab-ci.yml
-   package.json
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /app

ARG Nuget_CustomFeedUserName
ARG Nuget_CustomFeedPassword

COPY "TT.CS/TT.CS.API/nuget.config" ""
COPY "TT.CS/TT.CS.DAL/TT.CS.DAL.csproj" "TT.CS.DAL/"
COPY "TT.CS/TT.CS.BLL/TT.CS.BLL.csproj" "TT.CS.BLL/"
COPY "TT.CS/TT.CS.API/TT.CS.ConfigAPI.csproj" "TT.CS.API/"

RUN ls -al
RUN sed -i "s|</configuration>|<packageSourceCredentials><aws><add key=\"Username\" value=\"${Nuget_CustomFeedUserName}\" /><add key=\"ClearTextPassword\" value=\"${Nuget_CustomFeedPassword}\" /></aws></packageSourceCredentials></configuration>|" /app/nuget.config

RUN dotnet restore --configfile "/app/nuget.config" "TT.CS.API/TT.CS.ConfigAPI.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/app/TT.CS.API"

RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app/out "TT.CS.ConfigAPI.csproj"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TT.CS.ConfigAPI.dll"]
```

Outcome:

```
#17 3.891   Restored /app/TT.CS.BLL/TT.CS.BLL.csproj (in 1.58 sec).
#17 3.891   Restored /app/TT.CS.DAL/TT.CS.DAL.csproj (in 1.58 sec).
#17 3.941   Restored /app/TT.CS.API/TT.CS.ConfigAPI.csproj (in 1.67 sec).
#17 DONE 4.1s
#18 [build-env 11/14] COPY . .
#18 sha256:23c9d357832b3a7c1a8c5d607316f97c2fa09b51818f473a97f709f9cfeb981f
#18 ERROR: failed to prepare i2owcagafc3j7shg0slffonae: invalid argument
------
 > [build-env 11/14] COPY . .:
------
failed to prepare i2owcagafc3j7shg0slffonae: invalid argument
```

I've created a solution with a single folder sln/csproj without referencing the same solution projects, which works as expected but I'm still having issues with more complex solutions that combine multiple referenced projects with public and private nuget repos.
Does anyone see some obvious mistake? Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to fix this? i've been having the exact same issue

Comment: @VinArrow Yes, the key was to copy 'nuget.config' in each of the dependent projects that you need to restore. Also RESTORE command is not needed, it's implicitly done via PUBLISH.